# Расшифровка правил .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Помогите найти руководство по правилам .htaccess.

Нигде не смог найти. На сейчас интересует что означают эти строки

```
[R=301,L]
^(.*) 
$ - в самом конце строки урл
```

Comment: Это синтаксис модуля REWRITE сервера Apache. Спецификация находится здесь: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html